# Simple adding and subtracting puzzle

Tags: button, extjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

Okay so here's the story:

I have two buttons with two different controllers(handlers) - A plus and a minus button:

```
[ + ] addBtn        [ - ] subtractBtn - hidden
```

The first time you click the `addBtn`, the `subtractBtn` should show.

The max amount of clicks for either button is 2.

When you click the addBtn, the `count` of clicks should increment by 1.

When you click the `subtractBtn`, the `count` of clicks should decrement by 1.

When the `count` reaches 0, the `subtractBtn` should disappear

The issue here is I need to somehow store this variable(count) into a variable that both controllers can read.

If anyone can answer how this could be done in Ext JS, that would be muy excellente and I will provide tons of upvotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use count as a global variable and here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/x_window/HVkhy/1/

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
var count = 0;

var btnAdd = new Ext.Button({
    width: 50,
    text: '+',
    handler: function(){
        ++count;
        if(count > 0 && btnSubs.hidden)
            btnSubs.show();
        if(count > 1 && !btnAdd.hidden)
            btnAdd.hide();
    }
});

var btnSubs = new Ext.Button({
    width: 50,
    hidden: true,
    text: '-',
    handler: function(){
        --count;
        if(count < 2 && btnAdd.hidden)
            btnAdd.show();
        if(count < 1 && !btnSubs.hidden)
            btnSubs.hide();
    }
});

var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    width: 200,
    items: [btnAdd, btnSubs],
    renderTo: 'content'
    });

});
```

Comment: How could I allow different controllers to access the count variable? (i.e. different .js files)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the buttons have a common ancestor (maybe a container, or panel).  You could keep the variable there.  If you're using button handlers, you can access the parent container by using up()

```
handler: function(btn, e) {
    btn.up('container').count++; 
}
```

You may need to look over http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery to figure out which selector to use for the up() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can always access controller2 from a controller1 with the [getController](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-getController) method of the application instance, which you get in the [onLaunch](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-onLaunch) method of controller1.

```
application.getController("controller2").count++;
```